# Convert CSV file to import into lotus notes

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, lotus-notes

I have a `csv` file with 51 fields that I need to import using `quotation marks` and a `space` for each new record.  I am totally new to this and have looked at the CHAR 34 concatenation.
Is this the best way to do this? I have tried a small sample below but don't think that this is realistic for 51 columns. Can anyone guide me please?

```
ID  Date    ID Number       Conversion
1   2/12/17 ''1234''        "1","43071","1234"
2   3/12/17 ''5678''        "2","43072","5678"
3   4/12/17 ''4376''        "3","43073","4376"
4   5/12/17 ''9865''        "4","43074","9865"
5   6/12/17 ''1298''        "5","43075","1298"
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? The newer ones have `TextJoin()` which may help you greatly.

Comment: So, have you tried TexTJoin() then?

Comment: I typically suggest tab concatenation, easy to generate "/t", never heard of using multiple concatenation characters (" and a space)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `''5678''` is two single quotes on each side of the number, you can use the following (Also assuming your data starts in A2):

`=TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,""""&A2,""&B2&"",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"'",""))&"""")`

[image]